# Removing leading zeros in Find and Replace

Tags: excel

I wonder if it's possible to force Excel to not remove leading zeros while using Find and Replace option.

I want to use Find and Replace to change names to their codes (01, 02, etc). Some codes begin with 0.
I have three possibilities:

1. format cells as "nonstandard: 00" - Excel keeps for example `1` as `1` but displays it as `01`,
2. use apostrophe: `'01` - Excel keeps it as `'01` but displays as `01`,
3. format cells as "text" and just type `00`: it works while typing directly in a cell, but when I use Find and Replace option, before doing anything, Excel changes `05` to `5` even if I format cells as text and format it again in a Find and Replace window.

I want to use the third method, but it doesn't work.

Is it a bug or is it possible to turn off this Excel's officiousness?

I use Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the cell number format to text and then feed it a text value, you should have no trouble keeping your leading zeroes as a number-that-looks-like-text.

This example demonstrates it using the [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx).

```
Sub Set_Active_01()
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "@"
    ActiveCell = Format(1, "00")
End Sub
```

You should have no trouble replacing `ActiveCell` with the cell returned by a [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).